# Server path to User/Desktop?

Tags: windows, filepath

Anyone know if it's possible to read filenames (php) in C:\Administrator\Desktop\SomeFiles from a script in C:\inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\httpdocs?

As I'm sure you can tell, I know nothing about Windows servers.

I have a script that compares filenames from a database to filenames in a directory within the server's root directory (on a Linux server). Just not sure if you can, or how to, read outside of the site's root directory on a windows server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

File security is controlled by Access Control Lists (ACL) on Windows machines. Therefore the answer to your question depends on the ACL assigned to the folder you're trying to read from (and possible also its parent folders) and the identity of the user that is running the the php-script.

Comment: Thanks Mårten.I think it's a php issue though. I'm getting a php error that starts: Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect.

I found this solution (haven't tried it because I don't have access to the php settings): http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=258036

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by the hosting company. I'll try to get information on what they did. Just don't want to waste anyone's time trying to figure it out.